# find is not working as expected in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I want to get the anchor tag in order to make item clickable. Some how `find` element is not able get child element of DOM element. Till `eq(2)` I am able to get the correct `div` tile but couldn't able to get child as shown in the picture.

Cypress Test Runner Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ3Zp.png

```js
cy.find('form[name="createAuthActionForm"]').
        as('createAuthActionForm'). 
        find('div.icon-grid-flex-container>div').
        eq(2).
        find('a.icon-grid-item icon-grid-item--tiny'). 
        click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace space with a dot, like this:

```
cy.find('form[name="createAuthActionForm"]').
        as('createAuthActionForm'). 
        find('div.icon-grid-flex-container>div').
        eq(2).
        find('a.icon-grid-item.icon-grid-item--tiny'). 
        click()
```